# Approximation using Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$

Tags: calculus

Given question is that non zero root of $\sin x - x^{2} $ by approximated using first two terms in Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$. Any hints ? Thanks

Comment: @Amzoti can you please make it more clear

Comment: $0=-x^2+\sin x\approx -x^2+(x-x^3/3!)$

Comment: @Amzoti so i have to solve $x^{2}=6$

Comment: @Amzoti sorry it was typo , please see edited question that

Comment: @Amzoti yes i have found two roots which are -3 $\pm $ sqrt15 .but which one to take

Comment: @Amzoti oh yes i have got it thanks

Comment: @mike thanks ..

Comment: @Amzoti in textbookthey have rejected -3 -sqrt15 .Why so?

Comment: It won't be anywhere near an actual solution; it is so far from zero that it is badly approximating $\sin$.

Comment: Alternately it is not hard to see that there is no negative root: a root can only occur when $x^2$ and $\sin(x)$ have the same sign, but this won't happen for $x<0$ until $x<-\pi$, at which point $|x^2-\sin(x)| \geq \pi^2-1 > 0$. The proof that there is only one strictly positive root is similar.

Comment: @Ian thanks i see now

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ is:

$$ \sin x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$

which can be expanded to

$$ -x^2 +\left(x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!} ...\right)$$

I only expanded to 3 "expressions" with the purpose of getting a rough estimate of $\sin x$ to a couple decimals.

Source -> [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)